# W3SVC stuck at stopping state

Tags: iis

I have an Azure virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 R2) with active directory installed on it (PDC). On this server I have enabled the Web Server Role. W3SVC is running with local system account. Most of the times when I try to stop this service, it gets stuck in stopping state and after that only option is to restart the machine.

Please let me know how to investigate further. I have checked event viewer and IIS logs but can't find any clue.

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches

Answer (score 2):

This is solved by installing updates, apparently there was some issue with one of the recent Windows updates:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4345424/improvements-and-fixes-windows-8-1-and-server-2012-r2